# View controller suddenly wont connect to .h file

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, storyboard

I created a new View Controller, I then opened up and created a new filed (Objective-C class) and then created a subclass of UIVewcontroller.  I added my table views and labels in story board and now suddenly it wont connect them to the .h subclass Ive created.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to name that the view controller is part of your class. Select your view controller and on the third tab on the right write the name of your view controller. Here is a picture I got from this [tutorial](http://chrisrisner.com/31-Days-of-iOS--Day-4%E2%80%93Working-with-Multiple-View-Controllers-and-Storyboards) to help:

[image]